# Get XML schema used by sql column

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, xsd

I want to select xml schema assigned to a xml column in my SQL Server database, from a SQL statement.

I am stuck, I've looked in `information_schema.columns` with no luck, I can just alter it.

In Management Studio, in column properties under `Xml Type Specification` I can set (scheme collection) I want to simply select this from SQL statement.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should do it.

```
select C2.name
from sys.columns as C1
  inner join sys.xml_schema_collections as C2
    on C1.xml_collection_id = C2.xml_collection_id
where C1.object_id = object_id('TableName') and
      C1.name = 'ColumnName'
```